# Emulator is not connecting to the internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, nexus-5

I recently updated android studio & SDK to API 23 & run the app with google maps that for sure require internet access but Emulator does not get connected to internet. because of this google map services are not working. I am using Nexus 5 with Google maps API Emulator can you please tell me what's wrong with it.

I have app that gets lat, lng of the user & some basic functions like zoom-in zoom-out etc but due to Emulator not connecting to internet it shows lat,lng values as 0,0.

thanks

what should I do now